# How to verify `onclick` event in javascript for an Anchor tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

How to verify the onclick event asscoiated with the anchor tag in the html below:

```
<div class="itp-sb-left" style="float:left; width:100%; border:solid 1px #cccccc; padding:2px 0 2px 5px;">
            <a title="Submit to Facebook" target="_parent"  
             onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php? 
              s=100&p[title]=  
                 Singh&p[summary]=%27ll+try+to+describe+some+of+the+ideas+here.+Matrix+factorization+techniques+and+ensemble+methods+are+perhaps+the+algorithms+most+often+discussed+in+connection+with+the+Netflix+Prize%2C+but+a+lot+of+othe...&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jobma.com%2F1946&&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jobma.com%2Fpitcher%2FPhoto%2Fthumb_profile-1432116605.jpg', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">


<img alt="Submit to Facebook" src="http://www.jobma.com/images/facebook.png"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you wish to verify the following onclick JS event:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php? 
              s=100&p[title]=  
                 Singh&p[summary]=%27ll+try+to+describe+some+of+the+ideas+here.+Matrix+factorization+techniques+and+ensemble+methods+are+perhaps+the+algorithms+most+often+discussed+in+connection+with+the+Netflix+Prize%2C+but+a+lot+of+othe...&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jobma.com%2F1946&&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jobma.com%2Fpitcher%2FPhoto%2Fthumb_profile-1432116605.jpg', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
```

As this being opened in a new window so you could verify the opening of the URL in a new window as follows:

```java
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
String urlInNewTab = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertEquals(urlInNewTab, 'YOUR_EXPECTED_URL_HERE);
```